# A Java compiler plugin can change the AST of a compiled program. Is that a hack or is it officially supported?

Tags: java, plugins, compiler-construction

In Java, a compiler plugin is made by subclassing com.sun.source.util.Plugin (in Java 11). Java compiler plugins use classes that inherit from Tree, 
`https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.compiler/com/sun/source/tree/Tree.html`
These classes seem not to allow changes in the AST. However, some plugins, as those described in
      `https://bkushigian.github.io/2018/06/03/optimizing-javac-plugin.html`
and
      `https://www.baeldung.com/java-build-compiler-plugin`
do change the AST. The question is: is that a hack?

Comment: Define "hack"...

Comment: Code that uses non-documented features or fields and methods marked as Deprecated. In the Compiler Plugin Classes, there are some comments such as "do not use this, subject to change without warning". Even in public methods.

Comment: The baeldung article describes explicitly how it's done (didn't read the other). You tell us--is it a hack?

Comment: @DaveNewton, I do not know. It is hard to tell just by looking at it. A simple cast to a private class can make it a hack. The text ```http://blog.harmonysoft.tech/2017/10/how-to-write-javac-plugin.html``` seems to say that non-standard operations are necessary to change the AST. But even if this text and others hack the compiler APIs, that does not mean there is a way to achieve that without hacking. I need to cite the result in an article, so it is necessary an official reference (no one was found).

Comment: My experience of the Javac API is that the documentation is nearly non-existent. By your definition, that makes anything using it a hack ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not a hack. The examples are old/misleading (anything using `Method.setAccessible(true)` is always a hack) but the `com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner` visitor and `TreeMaker` factory are as official as the javac API is ever going to get.

From their javadoc:

> This is NOT part of any supported API. If you write code that depends
>   on this, you do so at your own risk. This code and its internal
>   interfaces are subject to change or deletion without notice.

This is their freedom to innovate without the *compiler* becoming a backwards-compatible mess like the main JLS/JDK sometimes is. You can understand why they would need this statement and I do not consider it a hack but it a warning about the amount of future maintenance you *may* need over time. IMHO sub-classing `TreeScanner` is quite accommodating of future language changes and I would not expect fundamental incompatibilities as new language features are rolled out.